# linked list - elements come after removing

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list

I have a `Node` class to implement linked list:

```
class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
        Node(int d){
            data=d;
            next=NULL;
        }
};
```

And in a solution class I have methods to insert, removeDuplicates, print etc;

Now to `removeDuplicates` my logic is:

- if my current's next node is null then return
- if current's value is equal to current's next's value then set next to current
- recurse with next

So here is my code:

```
Node* removeDuplicates(Node* head)
        {
            process(head);
            return head;
        }

        void process(Node* node)
        {
            cout << node->data << endl;
            if(node->next==NULL)
                return;
            if(node->data==node->next->data)
                node=node->next;
            process(node->next);
        }
```

when I call `removeDuplicate` method, it prints:

`1
2
3
4`

as expected, but after that when I again print with my another method, it gives me the whole linked list, without removing duplicates :
`1 2 2 3 3 4`

`display` method:

```
void display(Node *head)
          {
                  Node *start=head;
                    while(start)
                    {
                        cout<<start->data<<" ";
                        start=start->next;
                    }
           }
```

Comment: Your observations are correct. As shown, the duplicate removal code does absolutely nothing, and doesn't change anything in the linked list. Since the linked list exist solely by the virtue of `next` pointers (only they link the elements in the list together), any kind of changes to what's in the list would obviously require that the `next` pointers to be changed, somehow. That's the only way to change what's in the list. And, in all the code that removes duplicates, I don't see a single line of code that actually changes any `next` pointer. And that's why your code doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: agree with sam. In this code with line node = node->next you are essentially making the node pointer to to point to the next element in the list (not modifying the list). have to do something like this  temp = node-> next; node = node->next->next; free(temp); which makes the current node pointer to point to the next to next node (which would be the next node on the deleting the next node temp points to the next node which would be freed after wards.)

Comment: You never change the list at any point  (`node = node->next` just changes a local variable of that function, not anything in the list)

Comment: perhaps `node->next = node->next->next;` is what you want, but bear in mind you want to continue processing from the current node (not the next node) in that scenario in case there were three in a row of the same element. Assuming that the expected behaviour is to squash all three into one in that case of course.

Comment: ```while(head->next!=NULL)     { head=head->next; }            return head;``` if I use this inside process, how come I get only the last element ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your process function , please see the modified code below

```
 void process(Node* node)
 {
    cout << node->data << endl;
    if(node->next==NULL)
       return;
    if(node->data==node->next->data) {

       Node *tmp = node->next; 
       node->next = tmp->next;   
       delete(tmp); 
       //  node=node->next;

    }
    process(node->next);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following shown are the lines are from your code where you implement what to do when there are duplicates.

```
 if(node->data==node->next->data)
       node=node->next;
```

So what you are doing here is making node pointer move to next node. You should write code such that it skips the next node in case of duplicate and you can only do that by manipulating current node’s next pointer. Something like shown below:

```
 if(node->data==node->next->data)
       node->next=node->next->next;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the logic of your code and get the expected results, you just need to add exactly one character.
You need to replace

```
void process(Node* node) {...}
```

with

```
void process(Node*& node) {...}
```

The output will be as you wish.